# Can't properly change image's color using svg filter

Tags: html, css, image, svg-filters

| I have this image [image: original look] | And I need to make it look this way (at least, I need to fill the t-shirt fully) [image: look that I need] |
| --- | --- |

And I've got this:

[image: what I've got]

With this code:

```css
img {
  filter: url('#grayscale');
}

body {
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/csRyu.png">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="2">
            <defs>
              <filter id="grayscale">
                <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" 
                type="matrix" 
                values="1 1 1 1 1
                        1 1 1 1 1
                        1 1 1 1 1
                        -0.8 -0.7 0 1 0" 
                result="grayscale" />
              </filter>
            </defs>
          </svg>
```

How should I change the code to fill the red color fully? Would be very grateful to any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `saturate` filter can get you closer

```css
img {
  filter:saturate(0) url('#grayscale');
}

body {
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/csRyu.png">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="2">
            <defs>
              <filter id="grayscale">
                <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" 
                type="matrix" 
                values="1 1 1 1 1
                        1 1 1 1 1
                        1 1 1 1 1
                        -0.8 -0.7 0 1 0" 
                result="grayscale" />
              </filter>
            </defs>
          </svg>
```